# forcing usage of bitwise and instead of boolean and

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

In C++, a bool is guaranteed to be 0 or 1

```
C++ (§4.5/4):
An rvalue of type bool can be converted to an rvalue of type int, with 
false becoming zero and true becoming one.
```

Consider the following function and what g++5.2 generates with -O3

```
int foo(bool a, bool b)
{
    if(a&b) return 3;
    else return 5;
}


0000000000000000 <_Z3foobb>:
   0:   40 84 ff                test   %dil,%dil
   3:   74 13                   je     18 <_Z3foobb+0x18>
   5:   40 84 f6                test   %sil,%sil
   8:   b8 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%eax
   d:   74 09                   je     18 <_Z3foobb+0x18>
   f:   f3 c3                   repz retq 
   11:  0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)
   18:  b8 05 00 00 00          mov    $0x5,%eax
   1d:  c3                      retq
```

As seen, above, it is generating two test instructions which indicates that it is still treating the if as a if(a&&b) instead of a bitwise and.

Even if I first explicitly convert the two bools to two chars , it still generates the same output as above.

Since I know that the two operands a and b can only have 0/1 as values, is there some way to get gcc to generate just one test instruction. This is indeed what it does if the function takes two ints instead of two bools.

Comment: It could be covering all the bases for bool values.  Since a bool occupies a full byte, any nonzero value in that byte will make the bool true.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm : What you say is correct but my question is how can I force it to do something else

Comment: Are you concerned that the assembly is incorrect (it isn't), or that the optimised `bool` version is slower (it isn't)?

Comment: If you care about the assembly, write assembly; anything else could stop generating the code you hope for at any time, for no apparent reason.

Comment: Could you edit your question to be clearer about what you are objecting to and what you are asking?  "Is there some way to have gcc generate more optimized assembly for this function?" is quite a different question to what it seems your question is about based on the title and the first few paragraphs. It may also help if you show an exhaustive list of all the ways your function is called, since your objection seems to involve knowledge about what the non-boolean values were that were supplied as function arguments.

Comment: It's certainly strange. It's interesting that if you use `if (a == b)`, gcc simply emits a `cmpb` without worrying about the possibility that `a` and `b` might have different representations of `true`. Is it possible that under some circumstances gcc might omit normalization of a bool value? It seems unlikely, but you never know. Of the compilers available on gcc.godbolt.org, only ICC compiles `a & b` in the way you (and I) might expect.

Comment: @rici gcc.godbolt.org is awesome. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `&`, some compiler already produces different asm without jump:

clang 3.6 (rc2):

```
foo(bool, bool):                               # @foo(bool, bool)
    testb   %sil, %dil
    sete    %al
    movzbl  %al, %eax
    leal    3(%rax,%rax), %eax
    retq
```

A hack, in your case is to use `*` which has the same true-table for true/false

```
int foo(bool a, bool b)
{
    if (a * b) return 3;
    else return 5;
}
```

Which produces:

```
foo(bool, bool):
    movzbl  %sil, %esi  # b, b
    movzbl  %dil, %edi  # a, tmp70
    imull   %esi, %edi  # b, tmp70
    cmpl    $1, %edi    #, tmp70
    sbbl    %eax, %eax  # D.1960
    andl    $2, %eax    #, D.1960
    addl    $3, %eax    #, D.1960
    ret
```

[Demo](http://goo.gl/YlcV2d)

Comment: Good to know about clang, Given clang's better c++ conformance reputation, I guess this means that as per C++ specs, gcc should be able to do what I thought it should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

It is doing a bitwise-AND. That is the definition of what `&` does, and the compiler correctly implements the observable behaviour for bitwise-AND.

The operands of binary `&` undergo the *integer promotions*, so `a` and `b` are converted to `int`. The definition of this conversion is:

- `true` is converted to `1`
- `false` is converted to `0`

Doing a bitwise-AND, here is an exhaustive list of cases:

- `1 & 1 == 1`
- `1 & 0 == 0`
- `0 & 1 == 0`
- `0 & 0 == 0`

As you can see, this is the same list of cases are for a boolean AND. Therefore you cannot distinguish the operation merely by looking at the assembly output.

To confirm this, [here is an example](http://goo.gl/xdhjuF) showing that g++ generates the exact same assembly for `if (a&b)` as for `if (a&&b)` .

Remember that C++ is defined in terms of an abstract machine, and the output of the compiler may be anything at all so long as it produces the same observable behaviour as the abstract machine would.

---

You seem to be objecting to the part of the code associated with the conversion of `bool` to `int`.  Your compiler apparently has implemented `bool` such that any non-zero bit pattern is considered `true`.

So, extra steps are necessary. Performing `test %dil, %sil` would give the wrong result in the case that one of the bools had bit pattern `000...0010` and the other had `000....0001`, for example.

As user657267 points out in comments, the compiler has decided to test non-zero on one argument, and then test non-zero on the other argument, which it is easy to show that it fulfils the requirements of the defined behaviour for `&` along with the integer promotions as described above.

There's nothing you can do about this. You could submit a g++ patch so that it only ever generates bit pattern `000...0001` for a `true` bool and therefore it could use `test %dil, %sil` here but I doubt it would be accepted.

---

It would be *possible* to write code that reads the representation of `a` and `b` and performs `&` on the lowest byte. However this would be dangerous; the compiler might have decided to send some other bit pattern than you are expecting because it knows that those are acceptable bit patterns for `true`.

An alternative solution might be to change your function to accept `unsigned int` arguments instead of `bool`.  Of course this would introduce the possibility of new bugs, e.g. if you called the function with `1ull << 40` it would truncate `1ull << 40` to `0` and therefore behave the same as passing in `false`.  You can't eat your cake and have it; in this scenario you'd have to be very careful every time you call your function. (Maybe writing a wrapper class for `int` would help!)

Comment: Isn't the compiler just being smart and short-circuiting the evaluation, much like it would with a `&&`? It probably makes next to no difference here but it might with more complicated operators, like a function returning a `bool`, it might just have a single rule for handling all `bool` expressions.

Comment: @user657267 probably... the compiler has decided that this method is the best one for whatever reason , we can only speculate about that.   I'll clarify my answer

Comment: I'm unconvinced by the argument that gcc thinks that there might be more than one representation for true. It compiles `a == b` as a simple comparison, the same as `!!a == !!b` (which should normalize a and b if there is a possibility that it is necessary).

Answer (score -1):

I feel like this may not quite be what you are looking for but normally arithmetic and's can only be exicuted if the objects being tested are of type int so a simple cast may fix that but I would assume a cast could generate extra unwanted instructions that you don't want as well.

```
int foo(bool a, bool b)
{ 
    if((int)a&(int)b) return 3;
    else return 5;
}
```

Comment: This won't fool the compiler, it still knows they are `bool`s under the hood and is optimising accordingly. The emitted assembly is identical.

Comment: This changes nothing; the integer promotions promote `a` and `b` to `int` already.